# How to retrieve the detailed statements of an object's method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to retrieve the detailed statements of an object's method?
Supposed an class:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,make, model,year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        return self.make + ' ' + self.model + ' ' + str(self.year)
```

Copied it to console and create an instance.

```
my_new_car = Car('Mars_Rocket','MR5',2017)
```

Retrieve info:

```
In [52]: vars(my_new_car)
Out[52]: {'make': 'Mars_Rocket', 'model': 'MR5', 'year': 2017}
```

Nevertheless,what I want is:

```
{'make': 'Mars_Rocket', 'model': 'MR5', 'year': 2017 \
 'get_descriptive_name':'self.make + ' ' + self.model + ' ' + str(self.year)'}
```

One more step, I try `dir()`:

```
In [53]: attrs = [ i for i in dir(my_new_car) if not i.startswith('__')]
In [54]: attrs
Out[54]: ['get_descriptive_name', 'make', 'model', 'year']
In [57]: {attr:getattr(my_new_car, attr) for attr in attrs }
Out[57]:
{'get_descriptive_name': <bound method Car.get_descriptive_name of <__main__.Car object at 0x10517deb8>>,
 'make': 'Mars_Rocket',
 'model': 'MR5',
 'year': 2017}
```

Despite of acquiring the method, a detailed statement is still unloaded.

How to obtain the statement block of an object's method in interactive mode of console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a little helper that uses `inspect.getsourcelines` to grab the method contents:

```
from inspect import getsourcelines
from types import MethodType

def mydir(obj):
    names = [name for name in dir(obj) if not name.startswith('__')]
    for name in names:
        val = getattr(obj, name)
        if not isinstance(val, MethodType): 
            yield (name, val)
        else:
            val = "\n".join(map(str.strip, getsourcelines(val)[0][1:])
            yield (name, val)
```

this assumes an instance is passed and then goes through the names in the object and if they aren't of `Method` type it just returns their name and value. If they are it uses `getsourcelines`, removes the first line (function def) and strips indentation (probably *not a good idea*).

It yields tuples which you can feed into `dict`:

```
dict(mydir(my_new_car))
Out[33]: 
{'get_descriptive_name': "return self.make + ' ' + self.model + ' ' + str(self.year)",
 'make': 'Mars_Rocket',
 'model': 'MR5',
 'year': '2017'}
```

It grabs all contents in the method, `return` is also included (it's a statement).

Comment: what is MethodType?

Comment: @DFK the type of Method objects.

Comment: like `isinstance(val, car.get_descriptive_name())` ?

Comment: @DFK I had forgotten to include an `import`, my bad. It is equivalent to `isinstance(val, type(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name))`

Comment: get it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: `inspect.ismethod()`

Comment: @DFK it's another option, it [does exactly the same thing, though :-)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/inspect.py#L81).

Comment: lol, I might encounter to read the source code to find that they are of same definition after 12 months later with a normal learning progressing. Great!